# CSS file not loading with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a weird problem using mod_rewrite.

I have this code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+) article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And it seems to work because I'm able to rewrite

> localhost/article.php?id=1

in

> localhost/info/1

But the problem is that when I go to the page the CSS doesn't load, and I have only the content displayed.
I have a php file where I wrote the heading by calling a function

```
echo "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='it'>
        <head>
            <title>Website</title>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='css/index.php' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
            <script src='javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
        </head>";
```

I have also tried adding the slash before the "css/style.css", getting "/css/style.css" but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

use absolute paths  add / to URL:

```
echo "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='it'>
        <head>
            <title>Website</title>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <link href='/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='/css/index.php' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
            <script src='/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
        </head>";
```

Comment: i think you should add this in head of html 
   <base href="http://www.example.com/" />